# expand dropdown on focus jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am expanding the dropdown on focus which is same as clicking on the dropdown and selecting an option.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= ddlNature.ClientID %>').focus(function () {
                $('#<%= ddlNature.ClientID %>').attr('size', 6);
            });
            $('#<%= ddlNature.ClientID %>').focusout(function () {
            $('#<%= ddlNature.ClientID %>').attr('size', 1);
        });


          });
</script>


<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNature" runat="server" class="text" TabIndex="5">
```

The dropdown expands on focus but the option selected from the dropdown does not get selected ie. the expanded dropdown does not function as dropdown. I am not getting the value selected when i inspect in the firebug.

When I set AutoPostBack to true of the dropdownlist, I get the dropdown value but I don't want to refresh the page.

Thanks,

Comment: Why dont you use height() & width() functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is just fine..

Firebug does not display the select changes..

If you attach a change handler you will see that it does change it indeed..

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vxDrE/

Comment: just saw it looks great..but when we select value, Should not it close the dropdown like size = 1?

Comment: @Kamron, no because you told it that this size is 6.. you only revert it back to normal behavior when you tell it to set size to 1. but that happens on `focusout` (*when you click outside of the select box*)

Comment: @Gaby No the value is not selected because I am changing the value of another dropdown based on the value of the first dropdown.

Comment: I didnt post the question though. but i was curious if we select the data and dropdown should be back to normal, what changes should be done to code.

Comment: can someone pls help me with this it is very urgent pls

Comment: @asifa, is a postback happening when you select an option ? it might be causing the page to reload and perhaps reset the form (*based on what you do server-side*)

Comment: @Gaby when i set to autopostback the value is selected but the page refreshes i want to stop the page from refreshing without affecting the selected value. I tried e.preventDefault() but to no avail

Comment: @asifa, but the change in the other dropdown does it happen server-side ? or client-side ?

Comment: client-side. The value of the dropdown gets selected only when i set the autopostback to true but i don't want the page to refresh

Comment: @asifa, for debugging, did you add a `.change()` handler with jquery to confirm that the change does not happen (*client-side*)?